# Android Google Maps v2 Map Fragment in Dialog Styled Activity ActionBar Graphical Error - Samsung Tab 10 2

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, dialog

Interesting one this.

So we have a "Details" view that is shown over a GoogleMap, and for Tablets this activity is forced to be styled like a dialog.

This details view has a GoogleMap within it.

This works fine within our Nexus 10, however the Galaxy Note 10 2 (4.0.1) is having some real issues with this approach.

Graphically the ActionBar title and Home Icon and being made transparent, and also the Map in the Details view is being dimmed somewhat.

Has anyone come across this type of issue before? I can't seem to find anything around this.

Thanks

Make activity into "dialog" code

```
    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
private static void makeActivityIntoDialog(Activity activity) {
    //To show activity as dialog and dim the background, you need to declare android:theme="@style/PopupTheme" on for the chosen activity on the manifest
    //This will only be called for tablets over v11 so we are ok to ignore this warning
    activity.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    activity.setFinishOnTouchOutside(true);


    activity.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
    LayoutParams params = activity.getWindow().getAttributes(); 

    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    if (dm.heightPixels < dm.widthPixels){
        params.height = (4 * dm.heightPixels)/ 5 ; //relative height
        params.width = (4 * dm.widthPixels)/ 7 ; //relative width
    }else{
        params.height = (3 * dm.heightPixels)/ 5 ; //relative height
        params.width = (5 * dm.widthPixels)/ 7 ; //relative width
    }

    params.alpha = 1.0f;
    params.dimAmount = 0.5f;
    activity.getWindow().setAttributes((android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams) params); 
}
```

I have got it down to these lines of code which is causing the actionbar graphical error.

```
 mMapFragment = new SupportMapFragment();

             if (mMapFragment.isAdded()){
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().attach(mMapFragment);
             }else{
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.google_map_fragment_container, mMapFragment).commit();


             }
```

Basically the second i Add the GoogleMap Fragment to the view the action bar gets buggery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to place the map within a transparent frame layout - not sure why but it now does not cut out that strange transparent square from the title bar.

```
static public class WorkaroundMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment {

        public WorkaroundMapFragment() {
            super();
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutInflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle savedInstance) {
            View layout = super.onCreateView(layoutInflater, viewGroup, savedInstance);

            layout.requestFocus();
            FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
            frameLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
            ((ViewGroup) layout).addView(frameLayout,
                    new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
            return layout;
        }
    } 
}
```